# Win7: unregister event log from event source

Tags: c#, .net

A while ago I followed the MSDN example of how to write a windows service.  It included the following code:

```
    public Monitor_Processes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("Monitor_Processes"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("Monitor_Processes", "Monitor_Processes_Log");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "Monitor_Processes";
        eventLog1.Log = "Monitor_Processes_Log";
    }
```

It installed ok, but I got an error starting the service.  When I checked the event log it says: "The source 'Monitor_Processes' is not registered in log 'Monitor_Processes_Log'. (It is registered in log 'Application'.)"

I have since changed the code to look like this:

```
    public Monitor_Processes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("Monitor_Processes"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("Monitor_Processes", "");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "Monitor_Processes";
    }
```

But now, I still get the same error when trying to start the service (the error message is still referring to "Monitor_Processes_Log") -- even after an uninstall and a reboot.

How can I start fresh and have my source registered to the Application log (assuming my service will start successfully then)?

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the source,

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.DeleteEventSource("Monitor_Processes");
```

As a side note, I would advise you not to try to check if the source exists and create it during the execution of your service.  The EventLog.SourceExists() method requires administrative privs on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 because it tries to check the security log.  You should be adding these checks/create statements in your [ServiceInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx) class.

Dont make your Windows Services require local admin if possible.

Edit: to manually create the event log source, you can use PowerShell as well.

```
param (
    $logName = "Application",
    $source = $(Read-Host -prompt "Enter EventLog source"),
    $machineName = ".",
    [switch]$verbose
)

function createEventSource() {
    if (![System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($source, $machineName)) {
        [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource($source, $logName, $machineName)  
         Write-VerboseHost "Created source $source in log $logName."
    } else {
         Write-VerboseHost "Source $source in log $logName already exists."
    }
}

function help() {
    "Usage: Create-EventSource -source string [-machineName string] [-verbose]"
    exit
}

function Write-VerboseHost($message) {
    if ($verbose) {
        Write-Host $message
    }
}

if (!$source) { help }
```

Comment: Great advice about the admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks, Phil.  I deleted the event source and created it anew in a standalone program.  However, after I reinstalled my service I still get the same error when trying to start it.  It's as if my install is ignoring the new code.  I'm doing the installation from Visual Studio (after rebuilding the solution).

Comment: Make sure you remove the check too.  To write and event, you are probably wanting just to use the static method: EventLog.WriteEntry("Monitor_Processes", "Some message to write");   If you are still having problems, you could try wrapping your code in try/catch. In the catch handler, use Debug/Trace to write statement out. You could then use DebugView to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, but after trying everything I still get the same error when trying to start the service; so I'm giving up for now.  I obviously need to do some more reading about Windows Services.  (Apparently the MSDN example I followed isn't quite complete.)  I appreciate your efforts to try to help.